# Magento 2 js not loading after installing a new theme

Tags: magento-2.0, php-5.4, magento-2.0.7

This is my current magento 2 website 
http://jamesviana.online/

[image]
Above is the error
 I have installed a new paid theme which have been installed the backend is working while in the frontend the js not been taken.

I have tried to deploy the magento 2 cli commands in php bin/magento static:content:deploy but no use.

While indexing it shows this error

```
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/www/magento2/var/session/sess_69186e4b7bf9a9b00a807cc1452a452d, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/sites/j/jamesviana.online/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: SessionHandler::write(): open(/var/www/magento2/var/session/sess_69186e4b7bf9a9b00a807cc1452a452d, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/sites/j/jamesviana.online/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php on line 105' in /var/sites/j/jamesviana.online/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'SessionHandler:...', '/var/sites/j/ja...', 105, Array)
#1 /var/sites/j/jamesviana.online/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php(105): SessionHandler->write('69186e4b7bf9a9b...', 'adminhtml|a:0:{...')
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->write('69186e4b7bf9a9b...', 'adminhtml|a:0:{...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/sites/j/jamesviana.online/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61
```

I have given 777 permission for all folders I have tried with this cli command also

```
php -dmemory_limit=80G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Issue remains. In my local system with the same version and with the paid theme which is working good. only in my live server it have been showing this issue can anyone give a better solution to solve this it will be very helpful.

Comment: whats the mode ? is it production or developer on the server ? also removed all `var` `pub/static` folder and then try to run `setup:di:compille and static-content:deploy` give permisson 777 to var directory and then check

Comment: @Manthan DaveI have tried everything what you said from the first itself but the issue remains any other ideas?

Comment: can you check your console ? and post the screenshot what error it shows ?

Comment: @Manthan Dave I have already mentioned the error in my question itself I have attached the screenshot of the frontend view the error what I am facing is shown in the code view in my question itself

Comment: Not any js error are seen in your above site, please let you know when error are coming?

Comment: @Sri do one thing open the site in private window or remove browser cookie and cache it will works .

Comment: i think its working fine... here at my system... its looks good...

Answer (score 1):

Run following 2 commands, I am sure issue will be resolved:

1. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

I think your local server is running on windows(maybe Xampp or Wamp server) and your live server is running on Linux(maybe Ubuntu or Center-OS).
Linux has complex permission rule and mage 2 has a critical spot on it.

After run the cli commands and check permissions of all assets(js, css & images).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1. `sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. `remove MagentoRoot/var/` folder
3. `sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile`
4. `remove pub/static`
5. `sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
6. `sudo bin/magento cache:clean`
7. `sudo bin/magento cache:flush`
8. `remove browser cache`

then check.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all files from pub/static and var use command

```
rm -rf -R pub/static *
rm -rf -R var *
```

use following command to generate new files

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

now provide permission to these files

```
chmod -R 755 pub/static var
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes js are not loaded because of missing `.htaccess` in `var/pub/static` folder. Just check `.htaccess` file exists or not in hidden files also.